# as3 movie clip dynamic name from array is null

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

**I am using the code below and when I "trace(TheVar);" it is coming out null. Anyone know why?**

```
var TheVar:MovieClip; 
var myArray:Array = ["TheContent", "TheContent2"];

function RandomM()
{
    trace(myArray.length);
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    trace(myArray[r]);
    var TheVar:MovieClip =  myArray[r] as MovieClip;
    trace(TheVar);
}

RandomM();
```

### Update:

I am putting the full code to show what I am trying to do

```
this.stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
this.stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

var TheContent:Loader = new Loader();
var TheContent2:Loader = new Loader();

function Load1()
{
    TheContent.load(new URLRequest("1.png"));
    TheContent.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadContent);

    function LoadContent(e:Event)
    {
        addChild(TheContent);
        TheContent.width = ScreenX;
        TheContent.height = ScreenY;
        Load2()
    }
}

function Load2()
{
    TheContent2.load(new URLRequest("2.png"));
    TheContent2.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadContent);

    function LoadContent(e:Event)
    {
        trace("Jesus");
        addChild(TheContent2);
        TheContent2.width = ScreenX;
        TheContent2.height = ScreenY;
        RandomM();
    }
}
```

In the function `RandomM()` I want to change the Loader "TheVar" to one of these Arrays, where are also Loaders. I want to ultimately create a tween that will change between the loaders according to the swipe of a user.

```
var TheVar:MovieClip; 
var myArray:Array = [TheContent, "TheContent2"];

function RandomM()
{
    trace(myArray.length);
    var r = Math.round(Math.random() * myArray.length);
    trace(myArray[r]);
    var Base:Class = getDefinitionByName(myArray[r]) as Class;
    var TheVar:MovieClip = new Base();
}

Load1();



Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, fl_SwipeHandler);

function fl_SwipeHandler(event:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    switch(event.offsetX)
    {
        // swiped right
        case 1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 200 pixels to the right.
            TheVar.x += 200;
            // End your custom code

            break;
        }
        // swiped left
        case -1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 200 pixels to the left.
            TheVar.x -= 200;
            // End your custom code

            break;
        }
    }

    switch(event.offsetY)
    {
        // swiped down
        case 1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 200 pixels down.
            TheVar.y += 200;
            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
        // swiped up
        case -1:
        {
            // Start your custom code
            // This example code moves the selected object 200 pixels up.
            TheVar.y -= 200;
            // End your custom code
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

### ADDING UPDATES TO CLARIFY:

I have a LOADER named TheContent: here is the code:

```
var TheContent:Loader = new Loader();
```

I want to create SEVERAL "Loaders" that have images and SWF content. Then I want to move them off screen using ONE TWEEN but have the tween by dynamic so it will move different LOADERS according to what VAR I make the MovieClip in that TWEEN. To do this I will need to make the movie for the TWEEN... CHANGEABLE. I thought maybe the best way to do this is to create an ARRAY with all the NAMES of the LOADERS and then call them randomly and move the content in the TWEEN. Therfore I made an ARRAY:

```
var myArray:Array = ["TheContent", "TheContent2"];
```

But I simply can not get the random var out of the function RandomM(); So I can use it in a TWEEN later. That Loader is called "TheVar";

```
function RandomM()
{

trace(myArray.length);
var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (myArray.length -1) );


var theMC:String = myArray[r];
TheVar=this[theMC] as MovieClip;

trace(TheVar); //// TO BE USED LATER IN A TWEEN. 
///   IT WILL BE ONE TWEEN BUT WILL ANIMATE DIFFERENT MOVIES

}
```

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Your first block doesn't seem to be related to your latter additions which is why I got frustrated/confused and stopped providing help. Can you confirm firstly if your array contains STRINGS "TheContent" and "TheContent2" or instances of `Loader`??

Comment: Also may I suggest that `var r = Math.round(Math.random() * myArray.length);` should be `var r:int = Math.random() * myArray.length` to avoid going out of bounds.

Comment: oK I made some changes. Thanks so much.

Comment: So you have an array of loaders and you want to select a random one? Does that encapsulate the entire issue?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do. Perhaps the code can be entirely rewritten. Maybe I am doing it the hard way. But in short I want to call a random Loader and call a Tween function that I will create later to MOVE that randomly loaded loader accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edits, here's an answer that hopefully covers your problem.

Firstly like I mentioned, your array contains strings and not the loaders themselves. You want to do this:

```
var myArray:Array = [ TheContent, TheContent2 ];
```

Notice the lack of `"` wrapping each.

To select a random loader and assign it to `TheVar`, do this:

```
var TheVar:Loader = Loader( myArray[int(Math.random() * myArray.length)] );
```

You can now work with `TheVar` as expected.

Comment: But when I trace (MyVar); it just says [Loader Object]

How do I make it tween? var myTween:Tween = new Tween(TheVar, "x", Strong.easeOut, TheVar.x, 300, 5, true); - - WON'T WORK.

Comment: `TheVar` is your instance of `Loader`. Using `trace()` on an instance of a class calls its `toString()` method which generally returns something such as `[Object Sprite]` or similar.

Comment: So how do I fix it? :( I need to have access to TheVar to move it in a tween.

Comment: @PapaDeBeau There's nothing to fix, `TheVar` is a perfectly valid instance of `Loader` and can be manipulated with a `Tween` as expected.

Comment: What happens if you try the following: `TheVar.x = 10;` then `trace(TheVar.x);`.

Comment: I got it working now. My HUMBLE apologies. I don't know what happened or how it got working but it is. Thank you so much for your patience. I know now why you have the high reputation. Very good! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10159/discussion-between-marty-wallace-and-papa-de-beau)

Answer (score 3):

`"TheContent"` and `"TheContent2"` are strings, not MovieClips.

If these are instance names of MovieClips on the stage, you need to use something like this:

```
var myArray:Array = [this["TheContent"], this["TheContent2"]);
```

Or more simply:

```
var myArray:Array = [TheContent, TheContent2];
```

Assuming that you're working from the timeline.

---

If `TheContent` and `TheContent2` are classes that you have, you can use `getDefinitionByName()` to create instance of those classes from the strings you have. Example:

```
var Base:Class = getDefinitionByName("TheContent") as Class;
var TheVar:MovieClip = new Base();

addChild(TheVar);
```

Comment: Is there away to convert a string name to a movie clip name. These are Loaders that I am calling. Nothing is on the time line. All is dynamic. I was trying to convert the sting to a MC with this line: var TheVar:MovieClip =  myArray[r] as MovieClip;

Comment: If you want to take a string and use it to create an instance of a class you need to use [`getDefinitionByName()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getDefinitionByName())

Comment: I updated my code so you can see all of it and what I am trying to do. I am trying to Load multiple images and allow the user to swipe through them. I want to use ONE tween only so I need the MovieClip to be changeable so when the function is called it will Tween the next image/swf in the array. Make Sense?

Answer (score 1):

your issue is with this line

```
var r = Math.round(Math.random() * myArray.length);
```

random will give you a number from 0 to 1

```
myArray.length //will give (in your example) 2
```

lets say random gives you a value of .75 
.75 * 2 = 1.5
When you use the round function it will round to the nearest whole number in this case 2(1.5 and up are rounded up)
When you have a 2 it is out of your array index which should give you a null.
What you need need to do is

```
var r = Math.round(Math.random() * (myArray.length -1) );
```

Then you need to access the correct element and get the name of the movie clip

```
var mcName:String = myArray[r]
```

Then access to the movie clip itself

```
var THEVAR:MovieClip = this[mcName];
trace(THEVAR);
```

Comment: Thanks but I am getting this error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert flash.display::Loader@2ffa281 to flash.display.MovieClip. - AND WHEN I TRACE IT.. ITS NULL.